# Comment appeler précisément un lexique bilingue ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie

Dans mon entreprise, nous avons une liste de termes métier en français avec leur équivalent en anglais.

Certains collègues appellent cette liste un "glossaire", d'autres un "lexique".

Wikipédia http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossaire n'aide pas à y voir plus clair :

> [lexique] sera alors synonyme de vocabulaire, idiolecte, glossaire, dictionnaire, etc. En lexicologie cette confusion des sens courants n'est pas acceptable.

Donc, si *glossaire* est inexact et *lexique* imprécis, comment appelle-t-on une telle liste anglais/français ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le *lexique* et le *glossaire* sont considérés comme des dictionnaires par le Robert.

En ce qui concerne la question :

***Lexique***

> - Dictionnaire succinct (d'une science ou d'une technique, d'un domaine spécialisé)
> - *Dictionnaire bilingue abrégé*.

***Glossaire***

> - Dictionnaire qui donne l'explication de mots anciens, spéciaux ou mal connus.
> - *Lexique* d'une langue vivante, d'un dialecte ou patois
> - *Lexique d'un domaine spécialisé*.

Il apparaît donc que *lexique* est plus approprié pour transcrire les termes métiers dans une autre langue, le bilinguisme entrant dans ses définitions.

Il peut y avoir deux *glossaires* rédigés en français et en anglais pour expliquer très finement les mots ou expressions employés pour définir la spécificité de l'entreprise dans les deux langues.

Un *glossaire* enrichit de définitions approfondies ce qui est définit succinctement dans un *lexique*, sans les traduire dans une autre langue.

Si les termes métiers sont définis précisément dans un *glossaire*, et que ce dernier renvoie sur le mot correspondant dans une langue étrangère, sans traduire la définition dans cette langue, on devrait pouvoir le nommer *glossaire* sans heurter l'Académie française.

N.B. : L'emploi de ces deux mots a évolué, le Littré plus ancien ne mentionne pas le bilinguisme, en revanche l'Académie française l’inclus ; *glossaire* est dédié aux définitions spécifiques d'une activité.

Answer (score 6):

La lexicologie est une science et comme toute science a son jargon qui utilise des mots avec des sens précis, introduisant des nuances qui sont perdues pour les non initiés.

En pratique, *lexique* et *glossaire* sont utilisés pour ce genre de liste.  *Lexique* me semble plus courant pour des correspondances de mots comme celle qui est l'objet de la question; *glossaire* quand on va plus loin dans les explications.

Comment: Exactement, le lexique fait penser à des explication plus courtes que celles d'un glossaire. **Lexique bilingue** est très utilisée pour cette raison puisque il n'y pas des explications des termes dans les langues respectives.

Answer (score 4):

Dans le  monde de la traduction, on a tendance à utiliser **lexique bilingue** puisqu'un lexique donne les équivalence des acceptions, et pas des explications pour les termes dans chaque langue. Par exemple, on y verra:

accounting (dans une colonne) et comptabilité (dans l'autre).

Ici, je ne cite pas de reférence puisque je donne une opinion "métier".

Par contre, en anglais, on va dire ici : ***bilingual glossary***, puisque la distinction lexique c. glossaire n'existe pas vraiment. Il y a le  mot en anglais *lexicon*, mais le sens ne convient pas ici.

Souvent les entreprises postent ces listes sur les versions en anglais ou en français de leurs sites mais n'y mettent pas de lien entre les deux versions des lexiques. Cela fait que le traducteur ou rédacteur doit soit chercher la bonne direction dont il a besoin (anglais → français ou français → anglais) dans les sites, soit faire des recherches dans le lexique au cas où il n'y aurait qu'une direction.

Comment: I forgot the accent.  **lexicon** is an English word! Yes, as the only professional here in this area (so far), I know customary practices. My spelling in French sometimes fails me when I don't reread myself. Direction may not be adequate? There are many ways of saying this. Dans quelle direction traduisez-vous? Vers l'anglais, vers le français? A partir des quelles langues? Enfin, c'est un mot plutôt tecnnique...

Comment: direction: elles dépendent de la paire de langues étudiée et
reposent sur des ensembles de règles qui doivent être adaptées à chaque direction de traduction. http://taln2017.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/actes_TALN_2017-vol1.pdf/

Comment: Il est certain que je fais des fautes d'orthographe. Je suis interprète anglais<>français. Je ne pense pas que mon explication manque de clarté. Personne d'autre s'est occupé de donner les termes utilisés en français et en anglais. Mais bien, la personne qui a posé la question ne semble pas s'y intéresser. J'ai mentionné que c'était un terme technique parce que peut être je n'aurais pas du utiliser un terme que personne allait comprendre hors du métier. Enfin,il parait qu'ici les locuteurs "natifs" comme on dit soient les seuls qui ont le droit de cité....(homophonie voulue). Bonne soirée.

Comment: @onvousaouï  Il serait plus utile de répondre à la subtantifique moelle d'une réponse. Je ne trouve pas utile de dire que oui, c, c'est versus. Ou bien la réponse aide ou n'aide pas. Je vois ici des trucs en anglais qui sont vraiment risibles mais j'essaie d'évaleur le contenu grosso modo sans trop faire des cours d'anglais à moins que cela n'entrave vraiment la compréhension. Pourtant, on ne m'accorde aucun crédit. [image bancaire]

Comment: La verité c'est que j'ai n'ai pas de question, en générale. Je travaille vers l'anglais pour l'écrit et pour l'interprétation, ça va comme ça. Quand j'ai une question épineuse, je m'adresse directement à l'Académie. Ils sont très sympas. Mais, ce ne sont jamais des questions pour comprendre le français. Juste pour me confirmer une rédaction  ou usage inusité. Je ne suis plus "French language learner" pour ainsi dire. Le vocab. oui. C'est pour toute une vie. :)